# Count two time values and get the value in like a stopwatch format?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering how can I count two sets of time and then the value would like in a stopwatch format (00:00.00)

For example if the time is

```
05:00:00 to 10:53:34
```

How can I count the time?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to look at `TIMEDIFF(stoptime, starttime)` and other time functions.

```
TIMEDIFF('22:53:34','05:00:00')
```

might do it.

This does too.

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '22:53:34','05:00:00')
```

Comment: just want to ask if i'm doing this right i did `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF('15:00:00','13:00:01'), '%H:%i.%s');` and then got the result `01:59.59` i did it like this so its like in a stopwatch format, its correct right? I mean the stop watch format is `H:M.s` right?

Comment: what's the correct time format if i also want to get the milliseconds or is it microseconds? the .0 in the stopwatch. i tried it like this as the format `'%H:%i:%S.%s'` but the `%s` is still just getting the seconds, i need the milli/microseconds

Comment: For subsecond precision you need to be on MySQL 5.6.4 or higher and use `%f` to get microseconds in `TIME_FORMAT` and `DATE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 0):

with the function [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('10:53:34','05:00:00')
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb75b3/1)**

Please note that the output of the demo is formatted by the fiddle and not the same as if used directly.

If you want [fractional seconds](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html), I can't show you this in a fiddle, but this should work in MySQL 5.6.16:

You've got to adapt your CREATE TABLE statement and use the %f specifier for fractional seconds.

```
create table example12(
  starttime time(6),
  stoptime time(6)
  );


INSERT INTO example12 (stoptime, starttime) VALUES
(
    TIME(STR_TO_DATE('10:53:34.530', '%H:%i:%s.%f')), 
    TIME(STR_TO_DATE('05:00:00.000', '%H:%i:%s.%f'))
);


SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(
  TIMEDIFF(stoptime, starttime),
  '%H:%i:%s.%f'
)      
  FROM example12;
```

Comment: what's the correct time format if i also want to get the milliseconds or is it microseconds? the .0 in the stopwatch. i tried it like this as the format `'%H:%i:%S.%s'` but the `%s` is still just getting the seconds, i need the milli/microseconds